# Glycoprotein hormones metabolism

Tags: physiology, metabolism, endocrinology, carbohydrates

Why do the carbohydrate groups in glycoprotein hormones decrease the rate of metabolism? And increase the half-life?

Comment: can you give some specific examples of how glycosylated hormones have altered half lives and affect metabolism?